# What is the definition of strict equality (===) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Maybe it looks trivial, but is the following statement 100% true in Javascript?

`a === b` if and only if `(typeof a === typeof b) && (a == b)`

If yes, please provide a proof (pointer to `===` implementation?).
Otherwise, please provide a counterexample.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: Check [ES6 Specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison)

Comment: Yes, if `a === b` then `typeof a === typeof b` and `a == b`. How else would they be fully equal?

Comment: @Oka I'm genuinely interested in the mathematical definition of `===` in Javascript, knowing that it has things like `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, `NaN`, `+0`, `-0`, `undefined`, `null`. I just want to make sure that the statement above is correct for all these values. Maybe next time think twice before blaming someone for fishing for reputation.

Comment: Of course, `a != b` unless they're primitive data types. In other words a function is not equal to another same function. Likewise with an Object. Note that `typeof` on a Array will return `'object'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ES6 specification, 7.2.13 Strict Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison):

[image]

Pretty much the same in the [ES 5.1 specification here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).  The only thing that ES 5.1 leaves out is the part about Symbol values in step 7 since that is something that was added in ES6.

Comment: Point 2 (and 3) does not make any sense to me. Shouldn't it be "If Type(x) is Undefined and Type(y) is Undefined, return true"? It is a typo in the spec?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko If you pass step one then your two values must have the same type. There is only one valid value for each of type Undefined and type Null. See [sections 4.3.10-13 of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-undefined-value).

Comment: @Oka Aha! Now the spec makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the values have different types, the values are considered unequal. Otherwise, if the values have the same type and are not numbers, they're considered equal if they have the same value. Finally, if both values are numbers, they're considered equal if they're both not NaN and are the same value, or if one is +0 and one is -0.

```
var num = 0;
var obj = new String('0');
var str = '0';

console.log(num === num); // true
console.log(obj === obj); // true
console.log(str === str); // true

console.log(num === obj); // false
console.log(num === str); // false
console.log(obj === str); // false
console.log(null === undefined); // false
console.log(obj === null); // false
console.log(obj === undefined); // false
```

Strict equality is almost always the correct comparison operation to use. For all values except numbers, it uses the obvious semantics: a value is only equal to itself. For numbers it uses slightly different semantics to gloss over two different edge cases. The first is that floating point zero is either positively or negatively signed. This is useful in representing certain mathematical solutions, but as most situations don't care about the difference between +0 and -0, strict equality treats them as the same value. The second is that floating point includes the concept of a not-a-number value, NaN, to represent the solution to certain ill-defined mathematical problems: negative infinity added to positive infinity, for example. Strict equality treats NaN as unequal to every other value -- including itself. (The only case in which (x !== x) is true is when x is NaN.)